# Luring CC troops out with dragon attack i.e. only have 200 housing space for troops

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm focusing on getting 3 stars in a clan war. I'm TH 7. Using an all dragon attack usually works well. I usually drop lightening spells on the air defense. I was thinking of luring out the clan castle (CC) troops to be close to the air defense so when I drop the spell on it, they get zapped too.

My question is what's the best way to do this? In the past I've had trouble with walls not letting me get close enough to lour (though this usually doesn't happen). I've tried luring out CC troops using hog riders and it almost always works bad. I'm considering wizards or giants. The thing about giants is they're more likely to go deep into the base to get at the defense, thus luring out the cc troops. My camp has a capacity of 200 so that means 1 less dragon will give me 4 giants or 5 wizards. Any suggestion? I also thought maybe a mix of "bate" would work well as chances are 1 would get close enough to CC to lure.

Answer (score 5):

With a dragon attack if the clan castle is in the center, not luring the troops is the best way to go. When the dragons lure out the clan castle troops, they get pulled into the center allowing for much better destruction and a much higher chance of destorying the town hall. Clan castle troops are usally unable to do anything close to what will endanger dragons.

First of all, ballons, barbarians, valkaries will not be able to attack the dragons. Archers will all cluster into one group during the time when the dragon charges for his attack (which will wipe out the whole cluster). A pack of high level wizards will be the most danger for your dragons. A level 6 wizard has 270 dmg per attack, times 5 for TH7 and 6 for TH8, would be 1350 and 1620, but dragons have at least 1900 health. Though this cannot wipe out all your dragons, it will still critically injure them. But this is in the rare case when the opponent have all lvl6 wizards and all your dragons are clustered together.

Answer (score 2):

With a dragon sweep, you don't need to lure out CC troops. Unless you have a poison spell you can use.But otherwise, you can just sweep the base with rage or lightning if the Air Defenses are threats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to lure CC, but if you have to, I would suggest 2 giants/hogs + 1 wizard + 6 barbarians.

The giants or hogs will be used to pull out the CC and as long as all the CC are out, you will be good.

Once they are out, use the barbarians to move the CC troops onto the Air Defense (AD) you want to destroy. To do that, you will have to put the barbarian within range of a defense and on the opposite side of the AD.

You will basically be using the barbarians to make the CC walk and stay on the AD. It is important that these barbarians are within range of defenses so that the CC do not walk past the AD, towards the barbarian you dropped. It will take a bit of practice for sure, but it is definitely a viable option.

I think 2 giants/hogs are necessary for a couple of reasons:
- If the 1st giant/hog you send flies off a spring trap and remains unable to lure all the CC troops.
- If the CC is loaded with lots of small troops (takes more time to lure them all out).

The wizards will help against a defending dragon and barbarians will help move the CC onto the AD and/or distract any dragon for wizards to take out.

I still don't think luring is that critical at TH7, but I guess it does not harm practising it for later on when you have a bigger base to attack.